# OpenCV Android wrong coordinates

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm facing a very strange issue with OpenCV for Android :
when I'm accessing pixel with Mat.at  it gives me the wrong pixel on the screen :
A simple example :

```
for( double y = (mat.rows - h) / 2 ; y < (mat.rows + h) / 2 ; y++ ) {
    for( double x = (mat.cols - w) / 2; x < (mat.cols + w) / 2; x++ ) {
        for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ ) {
            mat.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
                saturate_cast<uchar>( 255 );

        }
    }
}

circle(mat, Point((mat.cols - w) / 2, (mat.rows - h) / 2), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
circle(mat, Point((mat.cols + w) / 2, (mat.rows - h) / 2), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
circle(mat, Point((mat.cols - w) / 2, (mat.rows + h) / 2), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
circle(mat, Point((mat.cols + w) / 2, (mat.rows + h) / 2), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
```

I should have the corners aligned with the box but not.
Is there a conversion to make in order to access to the true coordinates ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't post the initialization of `mat`, but it appears to be initialized as type `CV_8UC4`. This means that accessing the image using `mat.at<cv::Vec3b>` will give you incorrect pixel locations. Four-channel images must be accessed using `at<cv::Vec4b>` to give correct pixel locations, even if you are only modifying three of the channels, as in your example.

Unrelated: it's not advisable to use `double` as a counter variable type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but it might help you. Is this a SDK emulation? I remember having issues with thoes. When I tried my code in a device it worked like a charm.

Comment: No its on a device (samsung S3)